# How to switch windows from manual to safe mode with code in C#

Tags: c#, windows, safe-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows7 Force boot to Safe mode via API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897922/windows7-force-boot-to-safe-mode-via-api)

I want to put a button in my form that when someone click it system restart and go to safe mode.Does anyone how can I do it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897922/windows7-force-boot-to-safe-mode-via-api. In particular, check out the MSDN link in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could programmatically set the "boot.ini" switch [as described here](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=239780) and then [P/Invoke a call to `InitateSystemShutdown`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/InitiateSystemShutdown.html?diff=y).

Comment: boot.ini was discontinued with vista